# How to manipulate the option tags in the select tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help. I have a Dropdown containing "Automotive" and "Commercial".
What I need to do is if I click the Automotive, the second dropdown options will be filtered. All the options with the letter "A" in the last part will be displayed.

I just need to use javascript or jquery

[Click here to see the option tags that I'm referring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoSjD.png)

Comment: You should attach an event listener to your 1st drop down's onchange event, then check the drop downs selected option text to see if it is Automotive or Commercial, then do your filtering on drop down 2 inside the function attached to your onchange event

Comment: Please, Im new to jquery and javascript. Can you give an example.

Comment: Posted an answer below that should give you a good head start and hopefully explain some of the basics. I left the filtering of drop down 2 up to you as I don't understand from your post what exactly you want when it comes to filtering.

Answer (score 0):

'So, in your JQuery (this block should exist in a script tag or imported script file for the page):

```
 //document.ready() fires once the DOM has fully loaded, in otherwords all elements of the document have been rendered, 
 //you can then access them to do what we are doing here, which is attaching an event listener to your 1st drop down, 
 //and then inside that event's function do your second drop downs filtering based on the selection in drop down 1
        document.ready(function(){
            //The pound sign indicates the Id property of the element
            //In $(#dropDown1) replace the word dropDown1 with your drop down's actual Id
            $('#dropDown1').on('change', function(){
               //$(this) gets you the drop down element and .find() searches for the nearest decendant that meets the selector requirement, 
           //in this case element with tag option and attribute 'selected'
               if($(this).find('option:selected').text() === 'Automotive'){
                     //Do filtering of drop down 2 for Automotive selection
                     //Iterate your options, if they dont have a last letter
                     //equal to a or A hide() the element
                     //Do similar action when Commercial selected
                     $('#dropDown2 option').each(function(i, ele){
                         let lastChar = $(ele).text()[$(ele).text().length - 1];
                         if(lastChar !== 'A' && lastChar !== 'a'){
                            $(ele).hide();
                         }
                     });
               }else{
                     //Do filtering of drop down 2 for Commercial selection
                     //Change this to else if if you ever have more than 2 options
               }
             });
        });
```

Comment: So how about the filtering? If I click the Automotive, the options in the second dropdown with a letter A in the end will be displayed. How would I do that?

Comment: @Centi Please add to your question and give me an example of your second drop downs items before and after filtering (You can make it a small example)

Comment: @Centi I updated my answer to show you how to hide elements, now you just need to learn how to show them again and hide the other ones.

Comment: I included a photo to my question. That can be the example. If I click the Automotive. All the options in the Second drop-down with an A on its ending will be displayed and the non-A's will be hidden. But the opposite will happen if you click the Commercial.

Comment: Need help again. The code  is being written in the xsl file format. I didn't state that. So the options came form a datasheet.